# Select all Checkboxes within a form with multiple forms on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I've driven myself BATTY for the last 3 hours trying to figure this out.  I have 2 forms with different names on the page.  I am trying to have 2 sets of buttons to select/deselect all checkboxes in that particular form, but to no avail.  I have tried numerous iterations found here and elsewhere using pure JS and jQuery.  Please help before I loose what little sanity I have left :)

One big issues I have is the IDs and Names for the checkboxes are code generated (e.g. `<td><input type='checkbox' name=\"arIPInfo[$ID]\" id=\"IP$ID\" checked></td>\n</tr>` where $ID is a Database returned value)  The ID does not have to be as the name is the critical part to the other functions that use this data.  If the ID could be static say ID="IP" for all the checkboxes for form 2 and ID="Jacks" for form 1, that would be fine as well.

As it stands now, the jQuery and links were pasted from a working example found on StackOverflow which works fine on JSFiddle but not here.  I have jQuery 3.3.1 slim.

```
 <SCRIPT>
 function toggleCheck(state,elem) {
    jQuery(elem).closest("form").find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', state);
 }
 </SCRIPT>
<BODY>
<TABLE BORDER='1'>
    <TR>
            <TD CLASS='center'><H3>Jacks containing "<?php echo $_POST['SearchFor'];?>"</H3></TD>
    </TR>
    <FORM NAME="frmJacks" ACTION='' METHOD='POST'>
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="SearchOn" VALUE="JackList">
    <TR>
            <TD CLASS='center'><TABLE BORDER='1' CELLPADDING = '3'><?php echo getSearchResults('Jacks');?></TABLE></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR><TD><INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="acheck" NAME="TEST">
    </FORM>

    <TR>
            <TD CLASS='center'><H3>IPs containing "<?php echo $_POST['SearchFor'];?>"</H3></TD>
    </TR>
    <FORM NAME="frmIPs" ACTION='ips.php' METHOD='POST' ID='tempe'>
    <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="SearchOn" VALUE="IPList">
    <TR>     
            <TD CLASS='center'><TABLE BORDER='1' CELLPADDING = '3'><?php echo getSearchResults('IPs');?>
            <TD CLASS='center' COLSPAN=8><BUTTON TYPE="submit">Edit Selected</BUTTON></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
            <TD ALIGN='right' COLSPAN=8><a id="check" href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleCheck(true,this);" class="btn">Select All</a>&nbsp;<a id="uncheck" href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleCheck(false,this);" class="btn">Deselect All</a></TD>
    </TR>
    </TABLE></TD>
    </TR> 
    </FORM>      
    </TABLE>
```

Another jQuery I've tried: (note there are 2 in this function)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check-all').click(function(){
    $("#tempe").find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', true);
  });
  $('#uncheck-all').click(function(){
    $('form[name="myFormName"]').prop('checked', false);
  });
});
```

Comment: your example HTML above doesn't even contain two sets of buttons (only the second form has any) or two sets of checkboxes (only the first form has any), and the jQuery examples seem to bear no relation to the HTML in terms of the selectors your using. Did you just paste them randomly from somewhere else without having a clue what they do? Do you understand what the purpose of the selectors is? It's not clear exactly what's going on and what you've really tried. Try to give us an example where we stand some chance of actually reproducing the issue.

Comment: BTW your toggleCheck function looks like it should actually work ok, if you placed a second set of buttons.

Comment: And also your HTML is technically invalid, although most browsers will probably forgive you. You aren't supposed to put anything as the child of a table element apart from tbody, thead or tr elements. Putting a form element directly under table is not strictly allowed. You also appear to be trying to use tables to control the layout, which went out of fashion in about 2005 when browsers started to get more powerful at rendering - divs and CSS give you much more flexibility and are more correct semantically - tables are for presentation of tabular data, not setting positioning.

Comment: @ADyson I only had one set of links (as testing since it worked in the examples on JSFiddle) and have tried adding a 2nd set with no luck.  I've done my best to understand it but jQuery is new to me.

I wrote this back around 2008 but had some tight restrictions on (antiquated) browser versions.  It's undergoing a complete rewrite, but that's FAR from near finished.

Comment: @ADyson This works for ALL functions on the page, hence my attempts to hack it in some of my tests.
`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check-all').click(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', true);
  });
  $('#uncheck-all').click(function(){
    $("input:checkbox").attr('checked', false);
  });
});
<a id="check-all" href="javascript:void(0);">check all</a>
<a id="uncheck-all" href="javascript:void(0);">uncheck all</a>`

Comment: yep that would select all checkboxes on the page, it makes no attempt to look within a particular form. And since you've used IDs for the "click" selectors you can only have one of each type of button. I've written a working answer for you below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple `toggleCheck` function you've already got will work no problem if your HTML actually contains a set of checkboxes and buttons within each form.

Since your HTML is an unmitigated horror show of invalid structures, obsolete properties, missing closing tags etc, I've reduced it to a simple example to demonstrate that you're really quite close to achieving what you wanted:

```js
function toggleCheck(state, elem) {
  jQuery(elem).closest("form").find("input:checkbox").prop('checked', state);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<FORM NAME="frmJacks" ACTION='' METHOD='POST'>
  frmJacks
  <br/>
  <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="acheck" NAME="TEST" />
  <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="acheck2" NAME="TEST" />
  <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="acheck3" NAME="TEST" />
  <br/>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleCheck(true,this);" class="btn">Select All</a>&nbsp;
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleCheck(false,this);" class="btn">Deselect All</a>
</FORM>
<hr/>
<FORM NAME="frmIPs" ACTION='ips.php' METHOD='POST' ID='tempe'>
  frmIPs
  <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="bcheck" NAME="TEST" />
  <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="bcheck2" NAME="TEST" />
  <INPUT TYPE="CHECKBOX" ID="bcheck3" NAME="TEST" />
  <br/>
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleCheck(true,this);" class="btn">Select All</a>&nbsp;
  <a href="#" onclick="javascript:toggleCheck(false,this);" class="btn">Deselect All</a>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Oh common, mitigated horror show, it's not that bad is it?  Okay it is I admit it LOL :).  I've tested your example, works beautifully.  I then went back and stripped out all of the table elements and mine works as well.  Apparently my nightmare is giving DOMS/jQuery/JavaScript indigestion.  Guess I'll have a 1-off on the formatting of the pages.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: One question, what does the class="btn" do?  Is this some pre-defined CSS style on JSFiddle?

Comment: It doesn't do anything special. It's in the markup I copied from your original HTML for the buttons. I assumed you'd used it to style your elements.

Comment: Ah okay, I though it was something super-fancy other than CSS.  Thanks again for the help.  I've rearranged my <FORM> and <TABLE> objects and it seems to have cleared up it's migraine.

Comment: No problem. I would guess it was probably choking on the missing closing tags in particular, but it doesn't really matter, as long as you straighten it all out.